# StepMonitor won't display Plot

Tags: evaluation

This example is from the documentation under `Monitor`

```
data = {{0.18, -0.13}, {0.84, -0.06}, {0.05, 
    0.88}, {0.24, -0.63}, {0.67, 0.93}, {0.05, 0.88}, {0.65, 
    0.92}, {0.01, 0.99}, {0.17, -0.04}, {0.23, -0.55}};

model[{a_, k_, w_, p_}][x_] = a Exp[-k x] Sin[w x + p]

lp = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

I can successfully plot the steps using `Monitor`

```
Module[
 {
  vars = {a, k, w, p}
  },
 Monitor[
  FindFit[data, model[vars][x], vars, x,
   StepMonitor :> Pause[1.0]],
  Show[
   Plot[model[vars][x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}],
   lp]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can print the results using `StepMonitor`

```
FindFit[data, model[{a, k, w, p}][x], {a, k, w, p}, x,
 StepMonitor :> Print[{a, k, w, p}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As shown in the documentation I can extract the results using `Reap` and `Sow`.

```
steps = Reap[
  FindFit[data, model[{a, k, w, p}][x], {a, k, w, p}, x, 
   StepMonitor :> Sow[{a, k, w, p}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can then use the steps to plot the results.

My question is not about how to plot the results.

My question is why when I use `Plot` as an argument to `StepMonitor` I get no result.

I made various attempts. One is shown below.

```
FindFit[data, model[{a, k, w, p}][x], {a, k, w, p}, x,
 StepMonitor :> CompoundExpression[
   Pause[1.0],
   Show[
    Plot[model[{a, k, w, p}][y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}],
    lp
    ]
   ]
 ]
```

It gives me the results and takes much longer than running without the `StepMonitor` but no plots are shown on the screen.

I am confused as to why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from *Mathematica* version 6 `Show` by default has no side effects. In your particular case it just returns the `Graphics` expression to `StepMonitor` which does not use it because the latter is designed only for working with functions which have side effects like `Print` (side effect is printing of the expression and nothing is returned as the output) or `Set` (side effect is setting new value for the variable and this new value is returned as the output). As [Bob mentions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95496/280), you can add side effect to `Show` by the `DisplayFunction -> Print` option. The same effect can be achieved by writing directly to `"stdout"` with `DisplayFunction -> (Write["stdout", #] &)` or by writing to the `$Output` channel: `DisplayFunction -> (Write[$Output, #] &)`. But I personally prefer the `Dynamic` approach [demonstrated by belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95465/280).

Comment: I added your comment to my answer. If you wish, I will remove it from my answer. In either case +1

Answer (score 5):

You can put `Print` around the `Show`

```
data = {{0.18, -0.13}, {0.84, -0.06}, {0.05, 
    0.88}, {0.24, -0.63}, {0.67, 0.93}, {0.05, 0.88}, {0.65, 
    0.92}, {0.01, 0.99}, {0.17, -0.04}, {0.23, -0.55}};

model[{a_, k_, w_, p_}][x_] = a Exp[-k x] Sin[w x + p];

lp = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];

FindFit[data, model[{a, k, w, p}][x], {a, k, w, p}, x, 
 StepMonitor :> 
  Print[Show[
    Plot[model[{a, k, w, p}][y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}], 
    lp]]]
```

[image]

```
(*  {a -> 0.997279, k -> 0.104408, w -> -9.41643, p -> 1.56093}  *)
```

EDIT: Or explicitly set the `DisplayFunction` option for `Show` to `Print`

```
FindFit[data, model[{a, k, w, p}][x], {a, k, w, p}, x, 
 StepMonitor :> 
  Show[Plot[model[{a, k, w, p}][y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}], 
   lp, DisplayFunction -> Print]]
```

EDIT 2: Comment by Alexey Popkov added for clarity.

"`Show` by default has no side effects: it just returns the `Graphics` expression to `StepMonitor` which does not use it because the latter is designed only for working with functions which have side effects like `Print` (side effect is printing of the expression and nothing is returned into the `$Output` channel) or `Set` (side effect is setting new value for the variable, output is the new value of the variable). As @Bob mentions, you can add side effect to `Show` by the `DisplayFunction -> Print` option." –  Alexey Popkov

Comment: Your `Print` solution works well and produces a permanent record. Do you have a suspicion as to why simply using `Show` displays nothing?

Comment: @JackLaVigne - perhaps `StepMonitor` changes the `DisplayFunction` since explicitly setting `DisplayFunction` results in an output from `Show`.

Comment: @JackLaVigne `Show` by default has no side effects: it just returns the `Graphics` expression to `StepMonitor` which does not use it because the latter is designed only for working with functions which have side effects like `Print` (side effect is printing of the expression and nothing is returned into the `$Output` channel) or `Set` (side effect is setting new value for the variable, output is the new value of the variable). As @Bob mentions, you can add side effect to `Show` by the `DisplayFunction -> Print` option.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you so much. Totally confused as to what was going on.

Comment: @BobHanlon If you agree with Alexy Popkov's comment, could you add it to the answer?

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
Dynamic@f
FindFit[data, model[{a, k, w, p}][x], {a, k, w, p}, x, 
 StepMonitor :> CompoundExpression[Pause[.5], 
   f = Show[Plot[model[{a, k, w, p}][y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}],  lp]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Correct. The `Dynamic` is outside of the `FindFit`. My questions is why the `Show` doesn't display inside the `StepMonitor`.

Comment: @JackLaVigne The problem is that (for some unknown reason to me) the `DisplayFunction` is being redirected to nul in the current document. Try for example:

Comment: `obj = CreateDocument[];
FindFit[data, model[{a, k, w, p}][x], {a, k, w, p}, x, 
 StepMonitor :> 
  CompoundExpression[Pause[.5], 
   Show[Plot[model[{a, k, w, p}][y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}],
     lp, DisplayFunction -> (CreateDocument[#, obj] &)]]]`

Comment: Explicitly setting `DisplayFunction->Identity` doesn't help. It looks like a strange quirk. I am happy with using `Dynamic` outside of `StepMonitor`.

Comment: @belisarius Your interpretation is not quite correct: actually the output of `Show` is returned to `StepMonitor` which simply drops it. It is "by design", see also [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95459/stepmonitor-wont-display-plot#comment258526_95496).